# What does the bolded part mean?

Tags: meaning

The call produced a high-shouldered young fellow, with a round red face, a short crop of sandy hair, a very broad humorous mouth, a turned-up nose, and a great sleeved waistcoat of purple bars, with mother-of-pearl buttons, **that seemed to be growing upon him, and to be in a fair way — if it were not pruned — of covering his head and overrunning his boots.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the phrasing is at least dated, if not archaic. From OED:

> **be in a fair way of/to**  *- have a good chance of (doing, obtaining, or reaching something)*

As for what the entire bolded text means, a paraphrasing might be:

> *[The waistcoat] had the appearance of vegetation growing across his torso. It looked as if it might need to be pruned (cut back), to stop it spreading up to cover his head, and down to cover his boots.*

Answer (score -2):

It's from Charles Dickens' "The Haunted-House" (his hyphen).

http://www.pagebypagebooks.com/Charles_Dickens/The_Haunted_House/Chapter_I_The_Mortals_In_The_House_p4.html

So the bolded part was most likely added by someone else, writing about the story, probably to call attention to the old usage.

Comment: Erm... surely *Dickens* is "old usage"? It was a common enough construction a couple of centuries ago.